# Passing in memory html file to pdfkit

Tags: python, urllib2, pdfkit

I just downloaded a website with python

```
p =urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open('http://www.google.com')
html_content = p.read()
```

And now I want to write it to a pdf file:

```
pdfkit.from_file(??????,'test.pdf')
```

But how do I pass the html_content in the function?
It expects a file, but I don't want to save the file first as a html. Is there a way to pass the fetched html_content in the pdfkit.from_file function?

Note: I don't wish to use .from_url, I first want to fetch the page using urllib2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are `pdfkit.from_string`:

```
....
html_content = p.read()
pdfkit.from_string(html_content,'test.pdf')
```

and `pdfkit.from_url`:

```
pdfkit.from_url('http://www.google.com')
```

And, `pdfkit.from_file` read filename as the first parameter, it also accept file-like object; you can pass the return value of the `urllib....open` because it's a file-like object.

See [`pdfkit` usage](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit#usage).

Comment: But It looks like from_string, doesn't interpret the html... It just wants to write the text to a pdf?

Comment: Passing p as a file didn't work (it created a blank pdf) however, the from_string did indeed interpret the string and it created a nice pdf! Thank you!